# Check radio button based on stored value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check a radio button based on the value of a var in localStorage.

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" id="dayope" name="yardstick" value="Days Open" onClick="ableBtn()"> Days Open
```

SCRIPT:

```
var yardName = localStorage.getItem("yardstick");
$('input[name=yardstick][value=" + yardName + "]').prop('checked', true);
```

No errors, but no check either.

I also tried...

```
var yardName = localStorage.getItem("yardstick");
$('input[name=yardstick][value=" + yardName + "]').attr('checked', checked);
```

And that throws:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: checked is not defined
```

What am I missing?

Comment: may be use this: $('input[name=yardstick][value=" ' + yardName + ' "]'). check out the single quotes before and after the '+' sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add quotes.

```js
var yardName = "Days Open";
$('input[name=yardstick][value="' + yardName + '"]').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="dayope" name="yardstick" value="Days Open" onClick="ableBtn()"> Days
```

Comment: Adding single quotes around + yardName + was the answer!

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that `yardName` will not be part of your string, because you want to access the value you stored inside that variable:

```
var yardName = localStorage.getItem("yardstick");
$('input[name=yardstick][value="' + yardName + '"]').prop('checked', true);
```

Otherwise, what you are actually looking for is an `input` with the value `' + yardName + '`, as in

```
<input value="' + yardName + '" />
```

And this is not what you are looking for.